# Something similar to Eyefinity?

Tags: 10.04, xorg, hardware, drivers, alternative

Is there anything simular to Eyefinity for Ubuntu?  More the idea of turning 3 smaller monitors into one big monitor

Thanks

Comment: I am not an expert at xorg.conf, but my gut instinct tells me this should be trivial with the right parameters.

Comment: what video card/driver are you using? Nvidia's non-free one handles all this very nicely.

Comment: @contagious: Ya, that's what I use. It is pretty easy to configure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newly released (proprietary) [10.7 Catalyst drivers](http://blogs.amd.com/play/2010/07/26/ati-catalyst%E2%84%A2-10-7-driver-%E2%80%93-what%E2%80%99s-new/) from ATI specifically support Eyefinity under Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid).

The proprietary NVidia drivers also support multiple monitors rather well, allowing you position them in relation to one another.

In theory the Monitor Preferences also supports configuring multiple monitors in this way, but reports on the Ubuntu forums are mixed and I have no way to test this personally.